# How to prevent VideoView/MediaPlayer from stopping other apps' audio?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

In one screen I have a looping background video (upon which normal UI elements are shown), implemented with VideoView like this:

```
String resPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bg_video;
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(resPath));

// Hide controls:
MediaController controller = new MediaController(getActivity());
controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
videoView.setMediaController(controller);

// Use looping:
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setLooping(true);
    }
});

videoView.start();
```

The video works great. The only problem is that when this view is shown (or even before if using e.g. ViewPager), **music playback from other applications stops**.

The video I'm using has no sound itself. Is there a way to set the VideoView, or the MediaPlayer it uses, in a "muted mode"? I.e., tell it not to do audio at all, and especially **not to mess with other apps' audio**.

Tried `mp.setVolume(0, 0);` in `onPrepared()` but it has no effect.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I believe your answer is going to involve going through the [`AudioManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamSolo(int,%20boolean)) and playing with mute/solo settings for the stream. Because it is music from other apps you want to keep playing, you will need to set the audio stream for your [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType(int)) to a different value before calling `prepare()`.

Comment: @ab.helly: Yep, I'll post an answer when I have time.

Comment: @Jonik, can you post the answer?

Comment: @Ana: Actually what I ended up going was essentially the same as what [Łukasz posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31569930/56285). As ugly as it feels, copy-paste `VideoView` from Android sources and comment out `requestAudioFocus` call.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Copy paste `VideoView` from Android sources and comment out these lines:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

You could name the new class `MutedVideoView`, for example.

gist here: https://gist.github.com/vishna/7e9d3466bced8502fcdd

Comment: How do I compile the copied VideoView class. it complains 'cannot resolve symbol' on:
import android.media.Metadata;
import android.media.SubtitleController;
import android.media.SubtitleTrack.RenderingWidget;
import android.media.TtmlRenderer;
import android.media.WebVttRenderer;

Comment: The solution I went with (back in 2015) was essentially the same as this. "Ugly but it works." In the `VideoView` copy-pasted from Android sources, I also had to comment out some Subtitle and Metadata related code that wasn't compiling for some reason.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this with reflection?

Answer (score 10):

The accepted solution does not guarantee compatibility across all Android versions and is a dirty hack more than a true solution.  I've tried all forms of hacks to get this working, yet none have worked to my satisfaction.

I have come up with a much better solution though - switch from a `VideoView` to a `TextureView` and load it with a `MediaPlayer`.  There is no difference from the user's perspective, just no more audio stoppage.

Here's my use case for playing an MP4 looping:

```
private TextureView _introVideoTextureView;
private MediaPlayer _introMediaPlayer;

...

@Override
public void onCreate(...) {
    _introVideoTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
           try {
               destoryIntroVideo();

               _introMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SignInActivity.this, R.raw.intro_video);
               _introMediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(surfaceTexture));
               _introMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
               _introMediaPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
               _introMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error playing intro video: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {}

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {}
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    destoryIntroVideo();
}

private void destoryIntroVideo() {
    if (_introMediaPlayer != null) {
        _introMediaPlayer.stop();
        _introMediaPlayer.release();
        _introMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
videoView.setAudioFocusRequest(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_NONE);
```

(before `.setVideUri()` call)

Comment: this is available in api level 26 and above,w hat about devices with os below that

Comment: did you find any other answer for API level less than 26?

Answer (score 0):

**There's a solution for API level 26 and further. This is Kotlin way of keep video mute.**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            binding.viewView2.setAudioFocusRequest(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_NONE)
        }
```