# VideoView is stopping music player

Tags: android, android-videoview

Well I've done an app in android studio and this app has a video running in background for the Login. The video is in a VideoView and works perfectly but when I was testing it in my phone while I was playing music I noticed that it pauses the music player. How can I solve this?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    vid = findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video);
    vid.setVideoURI(uri);
    vid.start();
    vid.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
    usuRut = findViewById(R.id.usuRut);
    girPass = findViewById(R.id.usuPass);
    girId = findViewById(R.id.girId);
}
```

This is where I run the video.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent VideoView/MediaPlayer from stopping other apps' audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280191/how-to-prevent-videoview-mediaplayer-from-stopping-other-apps-audio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [setAudioFocusRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setAudioFocusRequest(int)) method. It's only available from API level 26

Comment: well that works, but how do I do that in previous API?

Comment: you can do this for the previous APIs
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31569930/2577423

Answer (score 5):

`videoView.setAudioFocusRequest(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_NONE);`

Comment: This is only available from api level 26 and up