# Android MediaPlayer, How to play video with no audio and not interrupt other audio streams

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have a `VideoView`, and I want to play a short looped video with no audio. The problem is, when I'm listening to a book or music through my phone and then I get to the activity that plays this looped video, my music is paused. Is there a way to play the video without interrupting whatever audio might be already playing on the phone?

```
videoView.setVideoURI(descriptionVideo.getUri(getPackageName()));
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.setVolume(0f,0f);
                    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    videoView.start();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent VideoView/MediaPlayer from stopping other apps' audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280191/how-to-prevent-videoview-mediaplayer-from-stopping-other-apps-audio)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the VideoView asked for audio focus.
You could try below
videoView.setAudioFocusRequest(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_NONE)