# stop android video view from blocking background music

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to stop the android video view from blocking background music.

I am using video view to display my two mp4 intro clips and they have no sound but as soon as I start playing them the background music gets stopped.
Maybe the solution is related with request_focus.

Comment: [How to prevent VideoView/MediaPlayer from stopping other apps' audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280191/how-to-prevent-videoview-mediaplayer-from-stopping-other-apps-audio)

Comment: solved my problem.